# Passing two images to a page control

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a TableViewController and a DetailViewController. I put a page control in the DetailViewController and i want this page control to display two images passed from the TableViewController. The images that the page control will display depends on the cell selected in the TableViewController.

So my problem is passing two images at the same time from the TableViewController to the page control in the DetailViewController and make the page control display the two images passed.

PD: I want my page control to display only 2 images no more.

Below you can see what i have been trying so far to solve my problem.

**My TableViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailView"]) {

         KTDetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];

         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

         dvc.passedDetailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.tableImgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

         ***THIS IS MY ATTEMPT WHERE I PUT A ARRAY INSIDE ANOTHER***

         dvc.passedPagePropImg = @[ @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"receta.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"cachorrita1.jpg"]],
                                    @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"saiya3.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"goku.jpg"]] ];
         }
    }
```

**My DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KTDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *passedPagePropImg;

@end
```

**My DetailViewController.m**

```
@interface KTDetailViewController ()

 // Page Control
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imView;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageProp;
 - (IBAction)imageChange:(UIPageControl *)sender;

@end

@implementation KTDetailViewController

- (IBAction)imageChange:(UIPageControl *)sender {

    ***THIS IS MY HEADACHE WHERE MY APP CRASHES*** 
    self.imView.image = [self.passedPagePropImg objectAtIndex: self.pageProp.currentPage];

    [self.pageProp updateCurrentPageDisplay];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your passing an array of two Arrays, and trying to headache it as it is one.

Try :

```
self.imView.image = [[self.passedPagePropImg objectAtIndex: self.pageProp.currentPage] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope this helps